# Anyway to scrape a link that redirects?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Is there anyway that I can make python click a link such as a bit.ly link and then scrape the resulting link? When I am scraping a certain page, the only link I can scrape is a link that redirects, where it redirects to is where the information I need is located.

Comment: Yes. But we don't know how to fix your program if we don't know more precisely what it does. Please provide a short (five or six lines) **complete** program that demonstrates your question. [Edit] your question to include the entire [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: `requests` automatically executes `HTTP` redirections and keep information about all urls in `r.history`. If page uses `HTML` redirection (in `<meta>` tag) then you can easily find this and use `requests` with this url. `requests` can't only redirect `JavaScript` redirections because it doesn't execute JavaScript and there can be too many possible methods of redirection to find url in code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 types of redirections

- `HTTP` - as information in response headers (with code [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), 3xx)
- `HTML` - as tag `<meta>` in HTML (wikipedia: [Meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh))
- `JavaScript` - as code like `window.location = new_url`

`requests` execute `HTTP` redirections and keep all urls in `r.history`

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://' + 'bit.ly/english-4-it')

print(r.history)
print(r.url)
```

result:

```
[<Response [301]>, <Response [301]>]
http://helion.pl/ksiazki/english-4-it-praktyczny-kurs-jezyka-angielskiego-dla-specjalistow-it-i-nie-tylko-beata-blaszczyk,anginf.htm
```

---

**BTW:** SO doesn't let put bitly link in text so I used concatenation.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript then you can use `Selenium` (or similar module) to open web browser (which will executed all JavaScript on page) and control web browser and get data, click buttons, etc.

Comment: if you know, that page redirect to url with `?variant=33334400198` then you can analyze HTML and JavaScript to find it and everytime get fresh value from code.

Comment: Please elaborate? I'm unable to scrape and find a correlation with that `?variant=33334400198` and the product, so adding that string on to the html doesn't seem possible, is Selenium the only way to accomplish getting that url?

Comment: sometimes all information are in HTML or in other files like javaScripts or data readed by AJAX/JavaScript and it is hard work to find it. But when you find it you can easily use it in code. But if you can't find it then you have to use `Selenium` or other tool/module (ie. `PhantomJS`, `PyQt WebKit widget`) which can execute JavaScript code.